# Input text background issue in jQuery Mobile after upgrading

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

First of all, following is the style I used

```
.iblack input,.iblack textarea
{
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 4px rgb(0, 0, 0) inset !important;
}
```

Earlier I was using jQuery Mobile 1.2 and jQuery 1.8 and things were fine. See the live fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/qPKLZ/

Today I upgraded to jQuery Mobile 1.3 and jQuery 1.9 to find that background style is not properly applied. Live fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/ECxve/

Can someone point me out what exactly went wrong?

I even tried `background-color` on the text input itself to find that same behavior observed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the first fiddle markup applies the rounded corners on the input element

```
<div class="iblack">
    <input id="hoursMon" name="hoursMon" type="number" value="" data-mini="true" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset ui-mini">
</div>
```

but there's an additional div wrapper in your second fiddle that handles the rounded corners instead

```
<div class="iblack">
    <div class="ui-input-text ui-shadow-inset ui-corner-all ui-btn-shadow ui-body-c ui-mini">
        <input id="hoursMon" name="hoursMon" type="number" value="" data-mini="true" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c"></div>
</div>
```

fix it by styling the div instead of the input...something like

```
.iblack .ui-corner-all
{
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 4px rgb(0, 0, 0) inset !important;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/ECxve/1/)